# using iframe to show file in https

Tags: iframe, https

I am using apache-tomcat-7 and testing my web application for https .

evrythig works fine , except from the iframe component .

I am using the iframe to show a file , like this:

Iframe src="#{myBean.aFilePathForPriview}"...

myBean.aFilePathForPriview is the string that holds the path for the file . 
(for example : C:\somefolder\somefile.txt) 
this iframe works o.k. on http application , but it seems like trying to put the file secure https page doesn't work .

The I frame only opened when I am allowing not secure data to be opened on the browser .

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the file you are trying to open is located in a folder inside your WebContent (inside your project ) the iframe will pass the file  securly when your server use ssl.